# What are the layer normalization dimensions in transformer?

Tags: normalization, transformers

In transformer training, the activations have three dimensions: batch, feature (i.e. embedding) and time (i.e. token). Layer normalization is applied, calculating statistics (mean, standard deviation) and  using them to standardise the activations before using learned parameters to scale ($*\gamma$) and shift ($+\beta$) them.

Which dimensions are normalized over, and which are independent?

Presumably the batch dimension is independent. I also presume the feature dimension is normalized. But what about the time dimension? (As it doesn't have a defined constant length, I suppose the separate time steps can't have separate learned parameters, so there's just one $\gamma$ and $\beta$ for the layer.)

Different sources seem to disagree on the definition of layer normalization. And I feel the original transformer paper ([Attention Is All You Need](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf)) and its layer normalization citation ([Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf)) are not explicit about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each sequence element, we normalize the feature corresponding to that element, ignoring information from other sequence elements. We then scale and shift this normalized feature using learned weights that are joint across all sequence elements.

Thus, at inference time the normalization is sequence element independent, but during training, the values of the scale and shift change during back propagation depending on values from all sequence elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you use any particular sources?

Comment: @Denziloe - Only the original paper - it doesn't say so explicitly, but since parallelization rather than sequential operations are the claim to fame, that wouldn't be possible if you needed to wait for the outputs of all tokens to perform layer normalization.

The answers here seem to agree that this is the standard approach:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88552/layer-normalization-details-in-gpt-2